# Why use import and require() in Node.js code?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am reading the source code at ["Type definitions for Express 4.16"](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts) and found this funny line (#18):

```
import serveStatic = require("serve-static");
```

Since `import` is the new way to work with modules in ES6, why above code is used or needed at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Type definitions for Express 4.16](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts) is written(index.d.ts) in typescript, Where `import = require()` is a TypeScript Syntax

**TypeScript - Modules (export = and import = require())**

The `export =` syntax specifies a single object that is exported from the module. This can be a class, interface, namespace, function, or enum.

When exporting a module using `export =`, TypeScript-specific `import module = require("module")` **must be used to import the module**.

*Reference : [Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)*